# pg_ctl: could not start server

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to execute PostgreSQL unsuccessfully on Ubuntu

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 11 database server                                               * Removed stale pid file.
Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl start -D /export/postgresql/11/main/ -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log -s -o exited with status 1:
2022-11-14 14:00:57.126 UTC [29005] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-11-14 14:00:57.126 UTC [29005] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-11-14 14:00:57.182 UTC [29005] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
                                                                                [fail]
```

There is no much information to tell me what is wrong. How can investigate this issue?

Comment: "Examine the log output."  Yeah, do that.

Comment: Where? The logs at `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log` contains **exactly the same** output I pasted.

Comment: Use the proper start scripts and tools. 1) Use `pg_lsclusters` to see what clusters are installed and their status. 2) To start either do `sudo systemctl start postgresql@11-main.service` or `sudo pg_ctlcluster start 1` main`.

Comment: That is very peculiar.  What version of Ubuntu?  How did you install?  Did you do any customizations to the installation or configurations?  Do you have any other versions installed?

Comment: the `pg_ctlcluster` renders the same result (btw: args seem wrong in the comment). Ubuntu is 18.04 but it is in fact running inside a container, no other version installed, but likely some configuration is done. Is there a way to get more verbose error output?

Comment: Could you share the docker-compose.yaml (or whatever it is that defines the container)?  If there is stuff in there that you don't want to share, you can remove it but then make sure the sanitized version still has the same behavior.

Comment: Yeah, it should have been `sudo pg_ctlcluster start 11 main`

Comment: This, `/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl ...` does not look correct. What is the content of `/etc/init.d/postgresql`?

Comment: Actually, `sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main start`. Actually, I think the issue is related to the environment where Postgre is executing, so I am not able to get more information for the logs (?) but at least I have identified a potential problem/solution

Comment: It works either way per `man`: *To ease integration with systemd operation, the alternative syntax "pg_ctlcluster version-cluster action" is also supported, as well as putting the action first (matching the ordering used by systemctl).*